# Alternative to element.getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript

I have been using getBoundingClientRect(). At the beginning, I'm getting performance issues due to this. If I remove this method from my code, there is working well. Any alternatives to getBoundingClientRect() in javascript.

In this sample, I have created 2000 elements in button click and changed their positions in another button click. In that, I'm getting performance issues when using getBoundingClientRect().

Anyone help me to resolve this.

```js
document.getElementById("click1").onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var ele = document.createElement("DIV");
    ele.id = i + '';
    ele.className = "square";
    ele.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;left: 200px; top: 100px");
    document.getElementById("marker").appendChild(ele);
  }
};

document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
  var markerCollection = document.getElementById("marker");
  var width = 20,
    height = 20;
  var radius = width * 2;
  var area = 2 * 3.14 * radius;
  var totalMarker = 0;
  var numberOfMarker = Math.round(area / width);
  totalMarker += numberOfMarker;
  var percent = Math.round((height / area) * 100);
  percent =
    markerCollection.children.length - 1 < numberOfMarker ?
    100 / markerCollection.children.length - 1 :
    percent;
  var angle = (percent / 100) * 360;
  var centerX = 200,
    centerY = 100;
  var count = 1;
  var newAngle = 0,
    first = false;
  var dt1 = 0,
    dt2 = 0;
  dt1 = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < markerCollection.children.length; i++) {
    if (i != 1 && (i - 1) % totalMarker === 0) {
      count++;
      radius = (width + 10) * count;
      newAngle = 0;
      area = 2 * 3.14 * radius;
      numberOfMarker = Math.round(area / width);
      percent = Math.round((height / area) * 100);
      angle = (percent / 100) * 360;
      totalMarker += numberOfMarker;
    }
    var x1 = centerX + radius * Math.sin((Math.PI * 2 * newAngle) / 360);
    var y1 = centerY + radius * Math.cos((Math.PI * 2 * newAngle) / 360);
    var offset = markerCollection.children[i].getBoundingClientRect();

    markerCollection.children[i]["style"].left = (x1 - (offset.width / 2)) + "px";
    markerCollection.children[i]["style"].top = (y1 - (offset.height / 2)) + "px";
    newAngle += angle;
  }
  dt2 = new Date().getTime();
  alert(dt2 - dt1);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .square {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: #555;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="click1">Create Element</button>
  <button id="click">Click To Change</button>
  <div id='marker' style="width: 350px;height: 200px;border: 1px solid red">
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not misreading your code, all you're using `getBoundingClientRect()` for is to calculate the width and height of an element you already know the width and height of (20x20px).

Just use your `width` and `height` variables directly, or possibly avoid having to do the offset calculation entirely, add `transform: translate(-50% -50%)` to the element's style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to get the midpoint of each element If I load a different length of text in each div element. In this case, I don't know each element's height and width. That's why I'm using getBoundingClientRects. This is my actual requirement.

Comment: Now, I have added some text into each div element. Please find the below sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-i6k8ap?file=index.ts

Comment: In that case, use `translate(-50% -50%)` and the browser will deal with centering the element around its origin.